# How to find $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

By plotting $\dfrac{1-\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}{x^2}$, we find that in sufficiently small domain near $x = 0$, $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

[image]

So the limit **seems** to be $0$.

Now I tried to evaluate it using [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/), it gives the limit to be $\frac{3}{2}$. How can this be true. Also how can we find the limit.

---

### $\text{EDIT}$

As Claude and choco have evaluated, the limit is indeed $\frac{3}{2}$. But why graphing it and superzooming into domain near $x = 0$ gives limit as $0$? I tried it with desmos and geogebra, both, on superzooming, give same limit, ie, $0$. But without superzooming, they too give $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are there so many "without L'Hôpital" questions going around these days? Is there a campaign going on aginst poor old L'Hôpital or do textbooks contain these types of questions?

Comment: You went too far, exceeding the software's accuracy. This is evidenced by the discontinuity of the plot, which should be smooth. But the values on the sides manage to indicate an approximation of the answer, $3/2$.

Comment: @Winther sorry, but we haven't covered l'hopital yet. Its there in next semester. I'll remove it.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. You dont have to remove it - It's a perfectly fine question imo. I was just curious seeing so many questions with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you know
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1,\qquad \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}{x^2}&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1+\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}{1+\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2 x \cos 2x}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2 x + \sin ^2 x -\cos^2 x \cos 2x}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2 x(1-\cos 2x) + \sin ^2 x}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(2+1)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}
\end{align}

Maybe you took a mistake when plotting a graph. When I plotted same graph in GeoGebra, It seems that as $x$ goes to $0$, then $f(x)$ goes to $\frac{3}{2}$.
[image]

---

**Edit for Claude Leibovici:**
[image]

---

**Edit 2:** When I set domain of $x$ too small, an error occured. The first is similar to the plot the asker showed us.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you plot $\frac{\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}{x^2}$ for me ? The problem (I think) is $1-(.)$ which takes us at the limit of machine accuracy.

Comment: Thank you! I think its a software bug. Rationalizing seems the easiest way!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I added plot you requested.

Comment: @choco_addicted i superzoomed into domain near $x = 0$. Try for yourself.

Comment: @Tim Oh, GeoGebra has same error when $x$ is very small. It may occur educational problems when someone is teaching limit.

Comment: Its a bug, after all this time. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @choco_addicted, We can use $$1-\cos^2x\cos2x=1-\cos^2x(1-2\sin^2x)$$

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be true. Consider the Taylor series $$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\cos(2x)=1-2 x^2+\frac{2 x^4}{3}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\sqrt{\cos(2x)}=1-x^2-\frac{x^4}{6}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ So, $$1-\cos (x) \sqrt{\cos (2x)}=\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{3 x^4}{8}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

I suppose that your graph suffers some lack of precision (we are at the limits of machine accuracy). Using illimited precision, for $x=10^{-8}$, the value I obtained is $$1.499999999999999962500000$$ which is exactly the value given by the above Taylor expansion. Quite close, isn't it ?

**Edit**

I performed the calculations in double precision (machine accuracy $\epsilon=1.084\times 10^{-19}$) for different values of $x=10^{-k}$. The following table gives $k$, the value computed for the function as well as the value of the corresponding Taylor expansion up to $O\left(x^8\right)$ and the value computed using illimited precision

```
 1     1.496267206702157     1.496267206682217    1.496267206702157
 2     1.499962501708455     1.499962501708455    1.499962501708455
 3     1.499999625000146     1.499999625000171    1.499999625000171
 4     1.499999996250594     1.499999996250000    1.499999996250000 
 5     1.500000000511509     1.499999999962500    1.499999999962500
 6     1.499999994006296     1.499999999999625    1.499999999999625
 7     1.500004547655420     1.499999999999996    1.499999999999996
 8     1.499993705633695     1.500000000000000    1.500000000000000
 9     1.517883041479706     1.500000000000000    1.500000000000000
10     0.000000000000000     1.500000000000000    1.500000000000000
```

As we can notice, already for $x=10^{-5}$, some problems start to happen. This is just due to accuracy in the subtraction.

Comment: true! Wolfram is also using taylor series, and gives the same limit, but my problem is that graphically plotting on desmos seems to give limit as $0$

Comment: The problem is $1-(.)$. Try to plot $ \frac{\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}{x^2}$ for the same range and tell me what you get.

Comment: i think its a software bug. thank you!

Comment: @Tim. I don't think it is a bug. Did you plot what I asked you ? What do you get. It could be interesting you add this new plot in the question.

Comment: I get it tending to +$\infty$ : http://i.imgur.com/UFd0068.png

Comment: Thank you! I used even smaller x and still it got closer to 1.5. So its just a bug.

Comment: @Tim. It is not a bug. It is normal. Tomorrow, I shall put some numbers to show you.

Comment: No I meant the graphing software desmos had a bug. It was showing strange shapes near $x = 0$. I didn't mean $F(x)=1.499$ is bug!

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
\frac{1-\cos x\sqrt{\cos2x}}{x^2}=
\frac{1-\cos x+\cos x-\cos x\sqrt{\cos2x}}{x^2}=
\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}+\cos x\frac{1-\sqrt{\cos2x}}{x^2}
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\cos x=1$, we just have to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{\cos2x}}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos2x}{(2x)^2}\frac{4}{1+\sqrt{\cos2x}}=
\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{2}=1
$$
So your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x\sqrt{\cos2x}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}+1=\frac{3}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can change the variable $\sin^2(x)=t$, and

$$\frac{1-\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(2x)}}{\sin^2(x)}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$$

becomes, after dropping the second fraction (of known limit $1$),

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1-2t}}t=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-3t+2t^2}}t.$$

By the well-known conjugate binomial trick

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-3t+2t^2}}t=\frac{1-1+3t-2t^2}{t(1+\sqrt{1-3t+2t^2})}=\frac{3-2t}{1+\sqrt{1-3t+2t^2}},$$

hence $$\frac32.$$

Comment: thanks! you were correct, its inaccuracy of software.

Comment: @Tim: This is unavoidable. Assume that some software computes with $10$ significant digits. Then for all values of the argument $x<10^{-5}$, it can only evaluate $\cos(x)=1.000000000$, and consequently, $1-\cos(x)=0$. This is called catastrophic cancellation, a well-known numerical phenomenon. You must *never* blindly rely on numerical values.

Comment: Yes, but one should always count on math!

Comment: I mean one can always rely on results from finding the limit mathematically, rather than graphically.

Comment: @tim: except for human error.