# Finding $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{180\sin x}{x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I am in ninth grade so I am an amateur in mathematics and with no training in limits. I self derived this limit to find the value of $\pi$.

I imagined a circle to be composed of infinitely small right triangles.

The central angle is $x$ and hence the side closest to the circum will have side $r \sin x $ (where $r$ is the radius)

There will be $360/x$ such triangles.

Comparing this to the already existing circumference formula we will get

$$\pi = \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{180\sin x}{x}$$

But I have seen in Math Stack Exchange 
itself that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1 $$

As seen in the first line of the accepted answer to this question here:

[How to find $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2x}}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652103/how-to-find-lim-x-to-0-frac1-cos-x-sqrt-cos-2xx2)

But shouldn't it be equal to $\pi/180$ as per my derivation? Where is my mistake?

Comment: You used $180^{\circ}$ instead of $\pi$ radians

Comment: @mufasa Yes I thought about it but x is in degree measure.

Comment: I think your x is in radians and 180 is in degrees... will extend comment because just read prior comments, you need to convert your 180 degrees to radians (2*pi=360 degrees).

Comment: @cagt no while calculating I put both of them in degree measure.

Comment: It might help if you showed your derivation

Comment: @cagt substitute the formula in a calculator and it comes down to pi.

Comment: You can't ask "where is my mistake?" and provide no work. We can't guess; we can't read minds............................... (at least I can't hehe).

Comment: @mufasa should I edit my question to show the derivation?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN - yes please

Comment: Ok I will show my derivation as an answer as it not directly connected to the question

Comment: Part of the question is usually the process you went through and with which you want to help, so it should be really part of the question.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN No, post it in the original question. It **is** directly related to the question. The answers sections is reserved for answering _your_ question, which is "where is my mistake?" You are not answering your question by providing your work.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN so your calculator angle units is in Degrees, which is the units you needed, the answer you have is in degrees.

Comment: @cagt thanks I got it. I have edited the question to show my derivation.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN great, I would just recommend you to start getting used to change calculator to radians when testing trigonometric functions, as most things posted here and in the textbooks assume the independent variable x angle units is in radians.

Comment: @cagt will do thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your calculations we get the side length of each right-triangle opposite the angle $x^{\circ}$ where the hypotenuse is of length $r$ is given by:$$r\times\sin(x^{\circ})$$
And the number of such triangles is given by:$$\frac{360^{\circ}}{x^{\circ}}$$
Therefore if we add up all these side lengths we get an approximation to the circumference of a circle of radius $r$ as:$$C\approx\frac{360^{\circ}}{x^{\circ}}\times r\times\sin(x^{\circ})$$
If we take this to the limit as $x\to0$ we obtain:$$C=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{360^{\circ}}{x^{\circ}}\times r\times\sin(x^{\circ})=360^{\circ}r\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^{\circ})}{x^{\circ}}=360^{\circ}r$$
We also know the the circumference of circle of radius $r$ is given by $2\pi r$. We can therefore conclude that:$$\require{cancel}2\pi\cancel{r}=360^{\circ}\cancel{r}$$$$\therefore \pi=180^{\circ}$$
This gives us the conversion of radians to degrees.

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure you are properly differentiating between *degrees* vs *radians.*** As far as I know, the answer is $\frac{\pi}{180}$ if you are in degrees, and $1$ if you are in radians.